# Solve $\text{Minimize} \max\{|x-a_i|, i=1,..,n\}$

Tags: optimization

I have to solve

$$\text{Minimize} \max\{|x-a_i|, i=1,..,n\}$$

For $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq ...\leq a_n$

My intuition says that this x is a point in the middle of the $a_i's$ but I am not sure that it is correct and how can I prove this.

Thanks!

Comment: over what do you take the min?

Comment: I edited. The question is exactly how it is in the book

Comment: ... it should be written somewhere where does $x$ live.

Comment: Well, I think it says to find the x that minimize the maximum distance between x and the given numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\max$ will always take its value either for $i=1$ or $i = n$. So the minimize will make these two scenarios equal (as small as possible), so the minimum is indeed at $(a_n + a_1)/2$, i.e. in the "middle" in some sense like you suspected.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by middle. Thanks !