# how to minimise difference of data?

Tags: optimization

I have a data $X(i)=i$, where $i \in ${1,2,3,4,5,6}, i want to find $u$ that minimises $max|X(i)-u|$. How to solve this problem, can you give a proof?

Comment: Hint: take $u=\frac{\max_i X(i)+\min_i X_i}{2}$, i.e. right in the middle between the highest and lowest of $X(i)$'s. (Why?) If $X(i)=i$, then $u=3.5$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop can you please prove this result or post the link which has proof

Comment: I would prefer if you can show that you have made some effort yourself. This is not a "solve a problem for me" site. Cf. "How do I ask a good question": https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Having said that, there is another hint (or, rather, two): (a) Let $m=\min_i X(i), M=\max_i X(i)$. Can you prove that, for *any* $u\in\mathbb R$ you have $|m-u|\ge \frac{M-m}{2}$ or $|M-u|\ge \frac{M-m}{2}$ ? (Hint: use the triangle inequality.) (b) Can you prove that $\max_i|X(i)-u|=\frac{M-m}{2}$ if $u$ is the number $\frac{M+m}{2}$?

Comment: (Also, I don't believe your problem is about $\max(X(i)-u)$ but about $\max|X(i)-u|$. Can you please check? With such an elementary omission, I am not sure I am really helping you with those hints above.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks man

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179866/solve-textminimize-max-x-a-i-i-1-n